# How to count same item with multi parameters in mrjob in python?

Tags: python, mapreduce, bigdata, mrjob, word-frequency

I'm trying to write a map-reduce function in python.
I have a file that contains product information and I want to count the number of products that are members of the same category and have the same version. like this:`<category, {count, version} >`

My file information is as follows:

```
  product_name   rate   category   id  version
       a           "3.0"   cat1       1     1
       b           "2.0"   cat1       2     1
       c           "4.0"   cat1       3     4
       d           "1.0"   cat2       3     2
       .             .      .         .     .
       .             .      .         .     .
       .             .      .         .     .
```

for example :

```
   <cat1, {2, 1} >
```

I wrote this code but in combiner function I don't know how can I count them.

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep

class MRFrequencyCount(MRJob):

    def steps(self):
        return [
            MRStep(
                mapper=self.mapper_extract_words,
                combiner=self.combine_word_counts,
            )
        ]

    def mapper_extract(self, _, line):
        (product_name, rate, category, id, version) = line.split('*')
        yield category, (1, version)

    def combine_counts(self, category, countAndVersion):
        yield category, sum(countAndVersion)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRFrequencyCount.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the key you are creating. Since you are essentially grouping by Category *and* Version you should send that as the composite key to the `combiner` function. The `reducer` can then break down the composite key and emit the data in the desired format.

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob
from mrjob.step import MRStep

class MRFrequencyCount(MRJob):

    def steps(self):
        return [
            MRStep(
                mapper=self.mapper_extract,
                combiner=self.combine_counts,
                reducer=self.reduce_counts
            )
        ]

    def mapper_extract(self, _, line):
        (product_name, rate, category, id, version) = line.split('*')
        yield (category, version), 1

    def combine_counts(self, cat_version, count):
        yield cat_version, sum(count)

    def reduce_counts(self, cat_version, counts):
        category, version = cat_version
        final = sum(counts)
        yield category, (final, version)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRFrequencyCount.run()
```

---

```
a*3.0*cat1*1*1
b*2.0*cat1*2*1
c*4.0*cat1*3*4
d*1.0*cat2*3*2
```

---

```
"cat2"  [1, "2"]
"cat1"  [1, "4"]
"cat1"  [2, "1"]
```